# Powershell codes to delete files in a specific way (with order)

Tags: powershell

A folder of 1900 files and I wish to delete files based on a set of pattern/order. I looked through everywhere, some very similar but also very different of what I'm looking for.

With below codes deletes set of 4s and keeps every 4th file is doable:

```
$mydir = 'C:\path\to\files'
[int]$idx = 1
get-childitem $mydir|sort-object {$_.Name} |foreach-object{
    if ($idx % 4 -ne 1){ #get the modulus
        $_ |remove-item
    }
    $idx++
}
```

Question, how can I get it to, for example skip 5 files, then delete 10 files and repeat? Also with the reverse order, delete 5 files, then skip 10 then repeat?

Comment: Just curious, is this a coding exercise? Or are you trying to solve a specific problem? I only ask because it's a very odd request.

Comment: I have a legacy program that extract files but somehow it creates a bunch of duplicate unsure the reason.  though extract files are good such as text and graphic files it create duplicate in weird ways sometimes not pertain to any set rule. so it would give 20 of one type, and then 8 of another something like that. this is the first step to over come this issue but different rule each time so its hard to figure out especially since i am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to skip/track the amounts you request. It should be simple to apply this to your use case, assuming one actually exists.

First we'll make up a fake list of 100 files named File1 - File100

```
$files = 1..100 | ForEach-Object {[pscustomobject]@{Name = "File$_"}}
```

Skip 5, delete 10, rinse and repeat.

```
$total = 0
$delete = 10
$skip = 5

Do
{
    $files | Select-Object -Skip ($total + $skip) -First $delete | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host Simulating deleting $_.name
    }
    $total += ($skip + $delete)
}
until($total -ge $files.count)
```

Skip 10, delete 5, and so on

```
$total = 0
$delete = 5
$skip = 10

Do
{
    $files | Select-Object -Skip ($total + $skip) -First $delete | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host Simulating deleting $_.name
    }
    $total += ($skip + $delete)
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply.  I just thought about something how you tackled this and used 100 files is that because it is divisible by both 5 and 10?  so if one were to change this rule to say 19 and 17, would this still work?

Comment: Of course, why didn't you just try it. Experiment!

Comment: Since it's selecting the first X objects, if there are say only 3 left and you say 10, it will still only get the 3.

Comment: alright I tried to combine it with my code and couldn't get it to delete anything. in fact, running the powershell file gives error. im not sure where to proceed from here.